# VB 2013 Comparisons between user input and application memory

Tags: vb.net, comparison

I've got two questions.

Firstly how would you compare for examble "My.Settings.ListBox1" of type "System. Collections. Specialized. StringCollection" to the content of "ListBox1"?

I have a number of items on my form (ListBoxes, Checkboxes and TextBoxes) for which the user can input data and I have created a menu item called save to which they can save the data to application memory so that when the form reloads the user doesn't need to inpuit the data.

That being said I would like to compare the latest user input to what is in memory so that when the user tries to exit the program, if they haven't hit save and the input doesn't match memory then a flag is raised and I can ask them whether they'd like to save or not.

But I'm stumped on this comparison if anybody can help?

Second question is about what I want to do with the comparisons. For each comparison I thought I could increment a counter, so that if all the comparisons aren't met and the counter is less than the maximum number then I can raise a flag and the user can be prompted to save. Much in the fashion:

```
Dim saved As Integer
saved = 0
If My.Settings.TextBox2 = TextBox2.Text Then saved = saved + 1
If My.Settings.TextBox5 = TextBox5.Text Then saved = saved + 1
If My.Settings.TextBox9 = TextBox9.Text Then saved = saved + 1
If saved = 3 Then Me.Close()
Else
```

*Then I will deal with the prompts at this point.

I've not tested this. Just a last minute thought before bed. But my question is, is there a more eloquent way of doing this? I'm sure there is. But this is the best my newbie VB brain could come up with at this hour.

Thanks for any help and suggestions!

Comment: If all you are trying to do is prompt the user, you may not need to.  Project Properties -> App | Save Settings on shutdown defaults to True.  Its almost never worth the effort to check.  for a) iterate the settings collection to see if the listbox contains each value b) No need for a counter, wouldnt you want to save if ANY are changed instead of just when ALL have changed?  For that, set a flag that is set in the TextChanged event. c) 1 question per post please.

Comment: So where dos ListBox1 get his items from ?? not from My.Settings.ListBox1 ??

Comment: Plutonix - At the moment when the various boxes are filled, I don't immediately save them to memory. I've created a save menu item that once clicked saves the contents to memory. That way if the boxes are filled with new data and the user restarts the program, the boxes don't hold that data unless the save button is clicked i.e. the form will load the last saved data. That's why I thought if the user updated any of the boxes but didn't hit save, I would compare what was in the boxes and what is memory and then ask the user if they would like to save if they close without saving.

Comment: Plutonix - That is what the counter does, if everything is the same and so the counter equals the max value than the form simply closes. However, if at least one thing is different from settings and the counter is short than I can create a prompt. Do you think this is an OK solution or there is a better way to do this? I will try and write and test something soon with regards to checking whether the contents of the listbox is the same as memory and post up.

Comment: Plutonix - I understand the idea of using a flag to determine if something is changed. But then I thought what if a box is changed, but then changed back to the same value as in settings. I think a comparison is more robust. But my program is very complex, so I may implement this idea for simplicity. Or maybe once a bis is filled I will immediately save to memory, and just have a clear all button if the user wants to start filling everythin anew.

Comment: Creator - ListBox1 get his items from folder browse dialog, and the box is filled with the folder names of the path that the user browsed to. I have been helped to create a For Each loop to save all the list box items to settings so that I can re-load them. But next I would like to compare, so if theres a difference I can detect and ask the user if they'd like to save before closing. I will try to write something soon and post up soon. What do you think to the idea of using a counter to see if at least one thing has changed? Do you have any other/better ideas? Thanks to all so far!!!

Comment: I tried this for the comparison with settings and listbox:

Comment: For Each s As String In My.Settings.ListBox1()
            For Each ss As String In ListBox1.Items()
                If s = ss Then
                    Me.Close()
                ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "Success!" Then
                End If
            Next
        Next

Comment: The above was unsuccessful however. Is this close to what you meant Plutonix?

Comment: a) if you want to make sure someone gets pinged put `@` before their name b) I stand by my first comment - the VB framework will save settings for you automatically. all that code to loop and test becomes cruft;  it alomsot certainly takes less time to simply `My.Settings.Save` than to execute that cruft.  It also introduces bugs like the counter - if you only prompt and save when it is at the Max, then that means *some* changes are not saved.

Comment: You're right. It is just "cruft". I'll just save user entries to settings and if the user wants to clear entries, I'll create a button for that. No need to over-complicate things, especially for what I'm actually building. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the textboxes didn't change you could do it like this.
Just start at textbox 1 if that's true then check textbox 2 , then 3 and so on.
As soon 1 is not true you can ask the user if he wants to save.  
Put in the Public Sub SaveTextBox() everything you want to save.

I just used a button for it ,but of course you need to use it in the closing event.
Maybe this is not the best way but it works.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.TextBox1
    TextBox2.Text = My.Settings.TextBox2
    TextBox3.Text = My.Settings.TextBox3
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If My.Settings.TextBox1 = TextBox1.Text Then
        If My.Settings.TextBox2 = TextBox2.Text Then
            If My.Settings.TextBox3 = TextBox3.Text Then
                Me.Close()
            Else
                SaveTextBox()
            End If
        Else
            SaveTextBox()
        End If
    Else
        SaveTextBox()
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub SaveTextBox()
    If MessageBox.Show("Save new settings ?", "My Application", _
     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) _
     = DialogResult.Yes Then
        My.Settings.TextBox1 = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.TextBox2 = TextBox2.Text
        My.Settings.TextBox3 = TextBox3.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```